# Difference between setting self.view.opaque = NO and setting the background color to clearColor?

Tags: ios, xcode, uiview, uicolor

Just wondering what would the difference be between setting the `opaque` property of a (background) view to `NO`, vs. simply setting the background colour of a view to '`clearColor`'. If I do the latter, would it be the case then that there would be no need to also set the `opaque` property to `NO` (as in `self.view.opaque = 0`)?

Comment: Try it. Set `opaque` to `NO` and the `backgroundColor` to clear. Note the result. Then try `opaque` set to `YES` and the `backgroundColor` to something other than clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the difference in the world. They have nothing whatever to do with each other. Neither has any effect on the other.

`opaque`, if `YES`, sends a message to the drawing system about whether or not it can save some cycles by not having to composite this view with what is behind it.

`backgroundColor` is, uh, the color of the background. If the background color is opaque and the view's `alpha` is 1, it is *your* duty to set `opaque` to `YES`. It will not happen all by itself.

**Big hint:** I do hope you are not confusing `opaque` with layer's `opacity` or view's `alpha`. That is yet another thing.

Comment: But setting backgroundColor to clearColor means you don't need to explicitly say self.view.opaque = 0, so it is a clean alternative, right?

Comment: @hinterbu Setting `backgroundColor` and `opaque` have nothing to do with each other.

Comment: @hinterbu You say you understand they are not related but you keep asking how one affects the other. They don't.

Comment: Ok, I think that what I wasnt quite getting is that the opaque property does not make the content more/less transparent and that even when a view is set as opaque, it can still be transparent. Is this correct?

Comment: Just returning to say thank you for the help - I thought about it, and if I think of opaque as meaning 'solid' rather than literally opaque I understand how it can still maintain transparency, in that it can at the same time be opaque, or solid, be transparent, and not draw something underneath.

Answer (score 1):

The [UIView.opaque documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiview/1622622-opaque?language=objc) provides a lot of detail around this and discussion as to how it works.

The `opaque` property is not the same as setting `backgroundColor` to clear.

Nor is it the same as setting the `alpha` value of the view.

The only thing it affects is how the OS draws the view inside the `drawRect` method. Allowing it to skip rendering passes for the view of set to `YES`.

It's all here in the docs.

N.B. Always read the documentation.

Comment: I have looked at the documentation and will go through it again but I don't understand what you meant with 'allowing it to skip rendering passes for the view of set to YES'.

Comment: @hinterbu rendering transparent views is very expensive. And a waste of cpu cycles if it doesn't need to be done. By marking a view as opaque you let the device know that it doesn't need to waste multiple cycles rendering your view as there is no transparency. Setting opaque does not change what your view looks like. If you are not sure. Don't touch it. Use alpha or backgroundColor depending on what you want.

Comment: Excellent, thanks. Please see my comment above. It was your wording of that important sentence that I couldn't make out - nothing to do with the explanation behind it.